# Mandrill reports using SwiftMailer?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am connecting to Mandrill's SMTP through SwiftMailers script, but I am not seeing an reports in Mandrill of the emails I send through Swift. Why is this happening?

Here is my code to connect to Mandrill (it's all working and sending mail as it should)

```
    include_once "../swift_required.php";
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 465, 'ssl');
    $transport->setUsername('our@email.com');
    $transport->setPassword('api-key-goes-here');
    $swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your SMTP header:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-Track', 'opens, clicks_htmlonly');
```

See more, http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages.